# process queues in infinite loop

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cpu

we have an online php game that requires handling tasks every second , we are doing that currently by running a cron job every minute to some script of ours via command curl -s in order to process some tasks by every second by looping for a whole minute with timeout 60 s .

we are facing 2 issues with that method :

1- sometimes queries takes more than 1 min , which then lead to lost data because the timeout
2- if we remove the timeout then sometimes we run into high cpu issues

it must be even second , the game is based on that mainly .

our current code is :

```
set_time_limit(65);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 59; ++$i){
  $this->doThings();
  sleep(1);
 }
```

I was thinking of using while instead of for to calculate the time 100% accurately is that better ?

the tasks usually not heavy , and our quires are well optimized as possible .

I tried increasing the timeout limit , and try to increase net_write_timeout in mysql cnf , that seems to well handled the issue but made overload cpu issue ..

I need an officiant way to handle our tasks every seconds without losing any data or creating an overload cpu ..

##UPDATE

the game is about wars and these stuff ,when player A attacks player B , there will be a distance between the 2 villages calculated by the system , lets say it's 5 min .

then it will be stored in db with table end_time = now + 5 min ,

so $this->doThings() will call queues from db that supposed to be executed now (end_time = now or less ) then loop them by their type to process accordingly .

what I meant "take over 1 min " I meant the whole cron task not one task ,sorry for bad explaining .

when a cron takes over 1 min , meaning the last queue me get lost , if we increased timeout then will be overlap and cause CPU overlap .

##UPDATE 2

is this code better ?

```
$timelimit = 59; //seconds
set_time_limit($timelimit + 1);
$start_time = time(); //set startup time;

while(((time() - $start_time) < $timelimit) || !$timelimit){
    $this->doThings();
}
```

Comment: Without details of what `$this->doThings();` does and an understanding of the overall application, it is not really possible to comment.

Comment: PHP really isn’t the best choice for an online game background. Regardless, why aren’t you using an _actual_ queue if you have messages you need to process? Push the messages to the queue, and have a queue daemon that continually processes these messages.

Comment: Don't use cron to call your script via curl. Run the script with PHP cli to avoid the unnecessary overhead of the web server. Why do _"sometimes queries takes more than 1 min"_?

Comment: 1. You probably don't need to be constantly running code in the background, just take the time between the current and previous requests and then calculate what happened in that time. 2. If you still need general server ticks then they can probably live on the 1+ minute time scale of cron. 3. If you're running code on time intervals of X and it takes >X to complete you can't hand-wave your way out of it. Either optimize the code, add resources, or break up the work. 4. At a certain point PHP is just the wrong choice for persistent daemons and/or multithreaded apps.

Comment: the issue is the whole app is already built on php , with live players .. switching to another language is an option I can not afford at the moment .. now I am facing issues with this current code , data either got lost during the timeout or get doubled by 2 cron jobs working at same time ( another one started while the first did not finish yet .. ) how can I at least make sure another cron won't start till first one finished , and without causing any issues during the timeout ?

Comment: so I should remove set_time_limit() from the cron , and make it works only with while loop using time < 60s ? as for the lock I have a table in db when start process I set its value to 1 , when start cron before call queues from db I check for its status , and it has timeout 240s , if its reached usually it means something wrong happened so it will reset . queue may be 1 , and may be up to 200 per each query , after we get them we start loop with switch case to determine its type and process accordingly

Comment: I have added the original code in the question

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) all php configuration information for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance-improving suggestions.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Do you need to do the tasks one after another?  Or do you desire to do multiple tasks at the same time?  How many tasks can run simultaneously without "piling up" -- I suspect it is no more than the number of CPUs you have.  Do you have to wait "at least 1 second" before acting again?  Or is it "at most 1 second"?

Comment: `cron` is usually a bad tool if the task cannot be finished before the next invocation of cron.  (This sounds like your case.)

Comment: I need to do tasks one by one , what other solution I can do other than cron ?